# Unzip: not found error while trying to install the Databricks CLI

Tags: curl, command-line-interface, databricks, wsl-2, databricks-cli

I am trying to download the Databricks CLI from this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/databricks-cli.html) through WSL2. I am connecting to WSL2 via the command prompt. When I run

`sudo curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/databricks/setup-cli/main/install.sh | sh`

I get the error

> sh: 77: unzip: not found

Is there any other way of downloading the CLI for WSL2? Git Bash is not an option for me unfortunately, due to fatal errors on downstream use cases. Are my proxy settings potentially screwed up? Should I be using powershell instead of command prompt, or does that not matter for WSL2? I am using the Windows Terminal software for both powershell and command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out my new, clean install of WSL2 was missing the unzip utility. First I ran

`sudo apt update`

and then I ran

`sudo apt install unzip`

and afterwards I ran the install code again, and it worked!

Comment: or you can download zip archive manually from https://github.com/databricks/cli/releases/latest and unpack using built-in archiver

Comment: oh man, I wish the documentation mentioned that! I just wouldn't know where to unpack it.